# Nodejs SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my index.js file, I have this error

```
C:\Users\Utkarsh\Desktop\LearningNode\notable\app\routes\index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ��c
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Utkarsh\Desktop\LearningNode\notable\server.js:11:1)
```

The actual contents of index.js is this:

```
const noteRoutes = require("./note_routes");

module.exports = function(app, db) {
    noteRoutes(app, db);
}
```

I have checked for weird quotes and directory names. Nothing is working. It seems that the problem is residing in this line.

```
const noteRoutes = require("./note_routes");
```

Edit:

**note_routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
    app.post("./notes", (req, res) => {
        // We'll create the note here
        res.send("hello");
    })
}
```

Node version is v8.9.4

I'm using sublime text 3.

Comment: what does your `./note_routes` file look like?

Comment: what version of NodeJS are you running? You can check by typing `node -v` in the terminal

Comment: `const` is not the first thing in your file. Try using an editor that is able to show you hidden things. Or place your cursor to the beginning of your `const` word, hit `ctrl+home` and `del`

Comment: @VtoCorleone see the edit.

Comment: Are you using babel or typescript?  How are you running your app with what command?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

OK. I found the solution to this issue.

The thing is that I created the `index.js` file in my project using PowerShell's `Out-File index.js` command. That might have caused some encoding issue.

On creating the file simply by `right-click > New file > index.js`, I get no such errors on running the code.

Comment: great find. I also created my index file with `touch index.js` and creating a new file normally worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it works. I deleted my index.js file and recreate it.

Answer (score 4):

1. **copy** content of first **index.js** file
2. just create new index.js file manually with right click context menu and **paste** same content in new index.js file

because it is **problem of different encoding** file created with shell.

Answer (score 1):

I meet same proplem.I use powershell command(`echo '' > index.js`) new create `index.js` file.

If you use vscode, you can use the following method.

1. open file in vscode.
2. click vscode footer UTF-16 LE (Select Encoding) button.

[image]

3. select `reopen with Encoding`

[image]

4. select `utf-8`

[image]

5. delete error string.

[image]

wow,this's ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, different solution.

The `index.js` file, which was created by PowerShell, is encoded with UCS-2 LE BOM.

To change the file so that node can run it (rather than deleting and making a new file) I changed the encoding to UTF-8 using NotePad++

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar problem. I just renamed "node_modules" to "old_node_modules" and executed "npm install" command. This took some time but problem got resolved and i got able to start the project. Later i removed the "old_node_modules" folder.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work with just files we need to use Notepad++(using it just run the file and remove the spaces wherever the error occurs) and save the file in a new folder wherein we again need to install node and dependent libraries using CLI and then it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have create your file using CLI . then it will give this error as 'Invalid or unexpected' . try creating file directly using GUI.It will help.

Comment: Hi, your answer is substantially a copy of the self-accepted one. Be sure, when answering, to add some value... Your answer may be deleted by the site editors. Please read [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).